# Multiselect DropdownList Values Insert SQL With ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multi-select, html.dropdownlistfor

There is just one value foreach loop according to the value I choose but ı want to have more than one value and save them into the database . how can I do these?

CSHTML..

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.Ehliyet.EhliyetId, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EhliyetList,  
    "Ehliyet Seçiniz...", new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" , @multiple="multiple"})
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult CreateTeacher()
{

    var ehliyet = EhliyetManager.EhliyetList();
    var list1 = new SelectList(ehliyet, "EhliyetID", "EhliyetAdi");
    ViewBag.EhliyetList = list1;

    return View();

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTeacher(User user, Teacher teacher, Ehliyet ehliyet)
{
    TempData["EventResult"] = TeacherManager.addTeacher(user, teacher, ehliyet);
    if (((SG_BLL.Tools.Result)TempData["EventResult"]).Status.Equals("error"))
    {


        var Ehliyet = EhliyetManager.EhliyetList();
        var list1 = new SelectList(Ehliyet, "EhliyetID", "Ehliyet");
        ViewBag.EhliyetList = list1;


    }

    return RedirectToAction("CreateTeacher");
}
```

Teacher Manager

```
public static Result addTeacher(User newUser, Teacher teacher, Ehliyet Ehliyet)
{
    using (SGContext db = new SGContext())
    {
        try
        {                    var TeacherEhliyetRepo = new Repository<TeacherEhliyet>(db);
            var ehliyet = EhliyetManager.EhliyetList();
            TeacherEhliyet teacherEhliyet = new TeacherEhliyet();


            foreach (var item in ehliyet)
            {
                if (item.IsChecked ==false)
                {
                    teacherEhliyet.EhliyetID = Ehliyet.EhliyetId;
                    teacherEhliyet.TeacherId = teacher.TeacherId;
                    TeacherEhliyetRepo.Add(teacherEhliyet);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ehliyet Manager

```
public static List<Ehliyet> EhliyetList()
    {
        using (SGContext db = new SGContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var repo = new Repository<Ehliyet>(db);
                var ehliyetList = repo.Listele().Where(d => d.IsChecked == false);
                return ehliyetList.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one the method will be hit for saving ?

Comment: addTeacher with TeacherManager

Comment: In add teacher there is no list , You are not taking list parameters

Answer (score 0):

Should this HTML Attribute @multiple= "multiple" instead of "true" ?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.Ehliyet.EhliyetId, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EhliyetList,  
    "Ehliyet Seçiniz...", new { @class = "form-control chosen-select" , @multiple ="multiple"})
```

And also, ListBox can also serve your purpose: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listbox.aspx